# Calculus 2 Series convergence - For which positive integers k is the series convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which positive integers k is the series given below convergent?
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(n!\right)^6}{\left(kn\right)!}
$$
I tried using Root/Ratio tests but that didn't work out. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Can we so the work from Root/Ratio tests?

Comment: Stirling's approximation?

Answer (score 2):

Setting
$$
a_n=\frac{(n!)^6}{(kn)!}.
$$
we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=&\frac{[(n+1)!]^6\cdot[(kn)!]}{[(kn+k)!]\cdot(n!)^6}=\frac{(n+1)^6}{(kn+1)\cdot(kn+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(kn+k-1)(kn+k)}\\
&=&\frac{(n+1)^6}{\prod_{i=1}^k(kn+i)}=\frac{(n+1)^6}{n^k\prod_{i=1}^k(k+i/n)}=\frac{1}{n^{k-6}}\cdot\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^6}{\prod_{i=1}^k\left(k+\frac{i}{n}\right)}
\end{eqnarray}
and therefore:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\begin{cases}
\infty & \mbox{ if } k<6\\
\frac{1}{6^6} &\mbox{ if } k=6\\
0 &\mbox{ if } k>6
\end{cases}.
$$
Hence the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n$ converges for $k\ge 6$, and diverges for $k<6$.